# Download múltiplos arquivos

Tags: php

Existe a possibilidade de fazer o download de múltiplos arquivos em um único link. Já tentei de diversas maneiras e não obtive resultado se alguém puder dar uma força.

Na imagem o `termosPedidoId` (78)

```
<?php

use App\Controllers\DB\Conn;
use App\controllers\Controller\Read;
use App\Controllers\Controller\Util;

$PDO = new Conn;
$Read = new Read;
$Util = new Util;

$result = $PDO->getConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_pedido_termos GROUP BY termosPedidoId");
$result->execute();
$dados = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($dados as $retorno){

    ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $retorno['termosPedidoId'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="models/downloadUpload.php?id=<?php echo $retorno['termosPedidoId'] ?>">Download</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php

}


// Arquivo que faz o download 

<?php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Controllers\DB\Conn;
$PDO = new Conn;

$pasta = '../uploadTermos/';
$result = $PDO->getConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_pedido_termos WHERE termosPedidoId=".$_GET['id']."");
$result->execute();
foreach ($result as $res){

if(isset($_GET['id']) && file_exists("{$pasta}/".$res['termosPedidoName'])){
    $file = $res['termosPedidoName'];
    $type = filetype("{$pasta}/{$file}");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type:{$type}");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    readfile("{$pasta}/{$file}");

    $handler = fopen("{$pasta}/{$file}");
    if ($handler) {
        while (!feof($handler)) {
            $buffer = fgets($handler, 4096);
            echo $buffer;
        }
        fclose($handler);
    }
    exit;
}
}
```

tem 03 arquivos estou conseguindo fazer o download somente de um. Na *query* estou colocando o `GROUP BY` para que não fique muito extenso o retorno do banco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível, ao menos não da maneira "ortodóxica". O protocolo `HTTP` foi desenvolvido para enviar apenas um arquivo por requisição.

Existem duas maneiras (estou em dúvida se a segunda ainda é possível) de baixar mais de um arquivo por link.

**Arquivo compactado**

Compacte todos os arquivos e um único arquivo compactado (`zip` por exemplo), no final das contas, baixará todos os arquivos através de apenas um arquivo.

```
$files = array('readme.txt', 'test.html', 'image.gif');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Se você analisar serviços de e-email (Outlook, Gmail, etc...), perceberá que você possui duas opções de download: de forma unitária ou um `zip` com todos os arquivos.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754359/1628790

**iFrame**

No passado isso funcionou, entretanto, não tenho certeza se os browsers ainda permitem tal solução.

Você teria que utilizar `javascript`, ou o próprio `PHP`, para criar um `iframe` invisível de cada arquivo que queira fazer o download. O `iframe` conteria apenas o código para download. Se você gostaria de realizar o download de 5 arquivos, seriam criados 5 `iframes`.

Caso gerenciado via `javascript`, você pode criar e excluir dinamicamente os `iframes`. Além disso, dentro do próprio `iframe`, como é um caso bem específico, você pode gerenciar via `javascript` situações de erro e chamar funçoes da página pai (a página que executa o `iframe`). Uma vez concluído o download, exclua o `iframe` do DOM.

Alguns exemplos:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670013/1628790
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45937933/1628790